# Blazor and EF ApplicationDbContext to get Loggedin user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side

I'm rewriting an application from .net MVC to Blazor.

In my old application I resolved DbContext and added current User in a BaseController.

With Blazor I need to resolve the Context in each Component, otherwice several Components will use the same DBContext at the same time, thus resulting in an error. According to MS Docs I should use the IDbContextFactory. But...It registers as a Singleton and I need the logged in user.

My Context has this Constructor:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
        : base(options)
    {
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var user = _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User.Identity.Name;
        LoggStuff(user);

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

If I register a factory like so:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

I get an error since the DBContext is not scoped but the AuthenticationStateProvider is.

I could change the factory to create the Context to be scoped I guess, but how would I pass the connectionString as an option then? Or is this the right way to go at all?

Comment: Wasm or Blazor-Server? You mention a BaseController, is this for an API?

Comment: The old app was .net MVC. This is Blazor-server. @BrianParker

Comment: @enet from what I can understand it is the correct way to get the user. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 but perhaps I'm missing something. My idea here is that I should not have to think about passing things from each page. Every call to the databse needs the user to be set inte the ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: [Polite] In Blazor the "User Context" and the "DB Context" are different entities.  What's your intent of mixing them?  Where is your "User" coming from?  How are you logging in?

Comment: I'm doubling up comments on @enet here, Do you need the user in the DBContext?  Or do you need the user to make specific queries?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes, I need the user in DbContext. The main purpose is that I log each transaction.

Comment: If I've interpreted your requirements correctly, you need to log each query against a user?  So, why not pass the user as part the query request to your backend data service?  Are you using unit of work `DbContext`s in your data services?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes, one option is to pass the user on every call to a middleware service, but that is repeating code over and over again. I think I might have a solution but I need to test i a little bit more to be sure it is working.

Comment: @ekenman - Can I add an "answer" with some suggestions that doesn't mean repeated code?  There's not enough formatting options in comments otherwise I'd add it here.   Some people get a bit A*** about answers that aren't really answers and mark them down!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Well, I wont vote any sugestions down. All help is appreciated.

Comment: NP.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the standard template weatherforcast context.  I'm writing an article on a similar subject so quickly adapted the existing code for your answer.  It's a bit long, but...

Basically you have a UI <=> ViewService <=> DataService <=> Datastore/ORM data pipeline (there would normally be an interface between the View and Data services, but I've kept it simple).  The View service is `Scoped` so has access to the registered `AuthenticationStateProvider`.  You can get whatever user object you want (I've just used Name).  I use request and result objects to pass data into the data layer and get results back, so pass the user information as part of the request.

Even if you've decided on a different course it will give you an alternative perspective.

This is my DbContext:

```cs
public class InMemoryWeatherDbContext
    : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecast { get; set; } = default!;
    public string UserId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public InMemoryWeatherDbContext(DbContextOptions<InMemoryWeatherDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

And my request and result objects:

```cs
    public record ListRequest
    {
        public int StartIndex { get; init; } = 0;
        public int PageSize { get; init; } = 10000;
        public string User { get; init; }  = string.Empty;
    }

    public record ListResult<TRecord>
        where TRecord : class
    {
        public IEnumerable<TRecord> Data { get; init; } = Enumerable.Empty<TRecord>();
        public bool Success { get; init; }
    }
```

This is my Data Service, It's registered as a Singleton.

```cs
public class WeatherForecastDataService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<InMemoryWeatherDbContext> _factory;

    public WeatherForecastDataService(IDbContextFactory<InMemoryWeatherDbContext> factory)
        => _factory = factory;

    public async Task<ListResult<WeatherForecast>> GetForecastsAsync(ListRequest request)
    {
        using var context = _factory.CreateDbContext();
        context.UserId = request.User;

        // Emulate logging
        Debug.WriteLine($"User : {request.User} requested a list of Weather Forecasts at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");

        IQueryable<WeatherForecast> query = context.Set<WeatherForecast>();

        if (request.PageSize > 0)
        {
            query = query
                .Skip(request.StartIndex)
                .Take(request.PageSize);
        }

        var set = await query.ToListAsync();
        return new ListResult<WeatherForecast> { Data = set, Success = true };
    }
}
```

And my View Service.  It's registered as Scoped, note getting the registered `AuthenticationStateProvider` on initialization.

```cs
public class WeatherForecastViewService
{
    private WeatherForecastDataService _weatherForecastDataService;
    private AuthenticationStateProvider _authProvider;
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Records { get; private set; } = Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();

    public WeatherForecastViewService(WeatherForecastDataService weatherForecastDataService, AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    { 
        _weatherForecastDataService = weatherForecastDataService;
        _authProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }

    public async Task<bool> GetForecastAsync()
    {
        var user = await this.GetUserAsync();

        var request = new ListRequest { User = user };
        var result = await _weatherForecastDataService.GetForecastsAsync(request);
        this.Records = result.Data;
        return this.Records.Count() > 0;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetUserAsync()
    {
        var state = await _authProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        return state is null
            ? "Anonymous"
            : state.User.Identity?.Name ?? "Anonymous";
    }
}
```

FetchData then looks like this:

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

@using BlazorApp6.Data
@inject WeatherForecastViewService ForecastService

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (this.ForecastService.Records == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    //.....
}

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync();
    }
}
```

### Appendix

For completeness.

I have a singleton pattern `TestDataProvider`:

```cs
public class WeatherTestDataProvider
{
    private int RecordsToGenerate;

    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts { get; private set; } = Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();

    private WeatherTestDataProvider()
        => this.Load();

    public void LoadDbContext<TDbContext>(IDbContextFactory<TDbContext> factory) where TDbContext : DbContext
    {
        using var dbContext = factory.CreateDbContext();

        var weatherForcasts = dbContext.Set<WeatherForecast>();

        // Check if we already have a full data set
        // If not clear down any existing data and start again
        if (weatherForcasts.Count() == 0)
        {
            dbContext.RemoveRange(weatherForcasts.ToList());
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            dbContext.AddRange(this.WeatherForecasts);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void Load(int records = 100)
    {
        RecordsToGenerate = records;
        this.LoadForecasts();
    }

    private void LoadForecasts()
    {
        var forecasts = new List<WeatherForecast>();

        forecasts
            .AddRange(Enumerable
                .Range(1, RecordsToGenerate)
                .Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                })
            );

        this.WeatherForecasts = forecasts;
    }


    private static WeatherTestDataProvider? _weatherTestData;

    public static WeatherTestDataProvider Instance()
    {
        if (_weatherTestData is null)
            _weatherTestData = new WeatherTestDataProvider();

        return _weatherTestData;
    }

    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };
}
```

The service registration code:

```cs
public static class WeatherAppServices
{
    public static void AddWeatherAppServices<TDbContext>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> options) where TDbContext : DbContext
    {
        services.AddDbContextFactory<TDbContext>(options);
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastDataService>();
        services.AddScoped<WeatherForecastViewService>();
    }

    public static void AddTestData(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        var factory = provider.GetService<IDbContextFactory<InMemoryWeatherDbContext>>();

        if (factory is not null)
            WeatherTestDataProvider.Instance().LoadDbContext<InMemoryWeatherDbContext>(factory);
    }
```

And then `Program` looks like this:

```cs
//.....
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddWeatherAppServices<InMemoryWeatherDbContext>(options
    => options.UseInMemoryDatabase($"WeatherDatabase-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}"));

var app = builder.Build();

// Add the test data to the InMemory Db
WeatherAppServices.AddTestData(app.Services);

//.....
```

Comment: Thenk you for your time on writing this answer. My goal is however to be able to call the context and not have to worry about setting parameters. That should be taken care of elsewere. Your view on this is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: NP - I know about factories - In old Blazor you had to write your own!  I use the pattern above to authorize CRUD calls from the UI into View Services against the user.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a Custom factory that I register like this in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>>(provider => new
    ContextFactory(options.Options, provider));
```

Since the factory is not Scoped and not a Singleton I can initate the DbContext from here with the current logged in user provided by the AuthenticationStateProvider. I've tested this to some extent and it seems to be working.

Comment: Do you have an example on your DbContext and RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider implementation?

Comment: I do not revalidate the User in the Ctx. I just need the logged in users username @Schoof. I'm running into problems mocking the Authenticationstateprovider now though...

Comment: But how do you pass through the user automatically every time? Or do you get the user on your backend first and then pass it along?

Comment: I Inject the AuthenticationStateProvider. This one gets the user.